# Screenshoting Or Screenshotting?

Tags: grammar, spelling, confusable

Which one is correct?

***Screenshot*** is probably a **noun**.

Is ***screenshotting*** grammatically correct? or it's just ***screenshoting***?

Comment: A synonym sometimes used by gamers is "screen archery".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct word is:

[Screenshotting](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=screenshotting) - The act of taking a screen shot.

However, as **Stephen** commented it's best to avoid it and say:

- take screenshots

**Screenshooting** sounds like an act of shooting (at) screens. **(this word doesn't exist)**

Answer (score 1):

As people have said, *screenshotting* is correct, but there are a a few alternatives:

> - To screenshot
> - To take a screenshot

Answer (score -2):

You "shoot" a picture with a camera. You are using your phone's camera to shoot a picture of a picture. It makes perfect grammatical sense for the correct verb to be screenshoot. "Sounds better" is never the right answer in grammar.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Do you have any dictionaries or other sources to prove this? Unfortunately, English grammar does not always "make sense".

Comment: You don't use your phone's camera when you take a screen shot.